How to place td at the end of row in HTML table?
I have a table and at some rows i want to place the td at the end of the row
something like these:



name
age
salary




john
20
1000


mike
35
2000


jessica
23
1100



status
ok






first name
last name
age
salary




john
smith
20
1000


mike
doe
35
2000


jessica
black
23
1100




status
ok



I know it can be done with adding an empty td and use colspan or having td for each one of them, but the problem is my table columns are not known and it is dynamic. and also it can be done with JavaScript but it is not an option for my case
I have searched for a lot of methods but found no solution

If your tables are dynamic then something is generating them and it will know how many columns exist. It will be much easier for us to answer if you tell us more about how these tables are generated.

they are comming from API calls, so as i said it can be done to have a td for each one, i did just that

You can simply use a ridiculously high number (here:1000) in the colspan attribute to make sure that this td will always cover all columns:


table {border-collapse:collapse}
td,th, caption {border: 1px solid grey; padding:4px}
caption { caption-side: bottom;
      text-align: right}
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jessica</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>1100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1000" style="text-align: right;">TD colspan: Status: OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sarah</td>
        <td>White</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>1100</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<caption>CAPTION: Status: OK</caption>
</table>



At the bottom I also added a second way of doing it via a <caption> element. However, it seems like the border around it looks different from the standard TD solution.
